import model in next js middleware
i am developing a fullstack app with next js.
for authentication, I need import User model file in my middleware.ts but when I import this in middleware file, Next.js return this error to me
export default mongoose.models.M_User || mongoose.model("M_User", M_user_schema);
how can I solve it?
my model is this :


import mongoose from "mongoose";

const M_user_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   phone: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   joined_at: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   avatar: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
   },
   refresh_tokens: {
      type: [String],
      required: true
   },
});
export default mongoose.models.M_User || mongoose.model("M_User", M_user_schema);



next js middleware file
